# How to populate values into a VBA array using the evaluate method and return them back to an Excel sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to populate an array with the values from the VBA `EVALUATE` method.  Once the array is populated, then I want to populate a range of cells in an Excel worksheet with the values from the array.

I wrote a `SUB` to do what I want, however when I run this function, I get the following error:

> Run-time error 9: Subscript out of range

**So my question is:** How do I correct my script to get `max_min_date2` to run correctly? A screenshot of my data [is upload here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwDeU.png)

```
Sub max_min_date2():

  'Define an array
  Dim values As Variant

  'Define the size of the array
  values = Range("L2:L1000").Value

    'Set up for loop'
    For i = 2 To 1000

     'Populate values in the array.
     values(i - 1) = Evaluate("=MAX(IF(A:A=" & Cells(i, 11).Address & ",B:B))")

     Next i

  'Populate Excel sheet with values in the array.
  Range("L2:L1000").Value = values

End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim Values(1 to 999) as Variant`

Comment: And get rid of the next line

Comment: BTW you need to either use fully qualified references or Worksheet.evaluate - Application.evaluate with unqualified refs always assumes whatever the active sheet is.

Comment: If you want to keep it the way you have then you need to realize that `values` is a 2 dimensional array and all references needs to include the 2nd dimension: `values(i - 1,1) = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub max_min_date2()

'Define an array
Dim values As Variant
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastRow2 As Long
'set the worksheet
With Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change to your sheet
    'get last row to avoid unnecessary loops
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row
    'get last row of ref data to avoid unnecessary calculations
    LastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'Define the size of the array make it a two dimensional for ease of assigning back to array.
    ReDim values(1 To LastRow - 1, 1 To 1) As Variant

    'Set up for loop'
    For i = 2 To LastRow

        'Populate values in the array.
        values(i - 1, 1) = .Evaluate("=MAX(IF(A2:A" & LastRow2 & "=" & .Cells(i, 11).Address & ",B2:B" & LastRow2 & "))")

    Next i

    'Populate Excel sheet with values in the array.
    .Range("L2").Resize(LastRow - 1).Value = values

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this works.  One follow up question:  What can be done to allow this script to run faster?  When I run this for `i = 2 to 100` it takes a while to return the values to Excel and so I am wondering what can be done to optimize the script since I have about 75,000 rows in my dataset.

Comment: Use the latest edit, it limits the ref data size and it fixed a error on the lastrow. @grantaguinaldo

Comment: @grantaguinaldo if that is still too slow for you. Post the working code on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to get ideas on speeding it up.

Comment: If you want to speed the code up, get rid of it and just do whatever you want to do in Excel. It seems strange to call an Excel function from VBA 1000 times just to return the answer to Excel as an array. Any time something goes between Excel and VBA it incurs overhead. So to speed up code, reduce that overhead by only bringing in things to VBA when absolutely necessary, and by bringing in an entire block of data in one go, rather than cell by cell. Suggest you edit your original question to describe the business logic behind this code, which will help people find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that you want to display each ticker's maximum and minimum dates. I do not believe the formula you've been working on will work as expected. Here's an alternate route, via a Pivot Table; you'll get your results real quick.

Paste this code into a code module:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CreateMaxDateByTickerPivotTable(ByVal prngTopLeftDataCell As Excel.Range, ByVal prngPivotTableTopLeft As Excel.Range, ByVal psPivotTableName As String)
    Dim pt As Excel.PivotTable

    Set pt = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set pt = prngPivotTableTopLeft.Worksheet.PivotTables(psPivotTableName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not pt Is Nothing Then
        pt.TableRange2.Clear
    End If

    With ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, prngTopLeftDataCell.CurrentRegion)
        With .CreatePivotTable(prngPivotTableTopLeft, psPivotTableName)
            .ShowValuesRow = False
            .CompactLayoutRowHeader = "Ticker"

            .ColumnGrand = False
            .RowGrand = False

            With .PivotFields("<ticker>")
                .Orientation = xlRowField
                .Position = 1
            End With

            .AddDataField .PivotFields("<date>"), "Max Date", xlMax
            .AddDataField .PivotFields("<date>"), "Min Date", xlMin
        End With
    End With

    Set pt = Nothing
End Sub
```

You can then call the sub above with a few parameters:

```
CreateMaxDateByTickerPivotTable Sheet1.Range("A1"), Sheet1.Range("K1"), "MaxDateByTicker"
```

The sub simply builds a pivot table (deleting it if it already exists), lists the tickers down and finds the maximum and minimum dates available in the data set for each ticker.